# Loki Beta2: laptop suspend issue

Tags: suspend, pantheon

When my close my laptop it goes into suspend mode.
After opening my laptop my screen stays black. I have to shut my laptop down, turn it on again and when I log in then my desktop does not boot. I have to restart it gracefully, after that it works again. How can I diagnose the issue? It seems to be an issue with pantheon-greeter.

I've managed to workaround this by changing the behaviour to sleep mode for now.

i3 4030u
HD4000

Comment: I have the same problem in the final release of loki, on a system with similar i3 procesor and hd4000 video chip.

Comment: Im also affected by this issue, could someone provide info what logs to check so we could fill a bug report?